Confusion regarding the definition of potential energy
Consider a ball on a mountain. At the top of the mountain, the ball has potential energy $mgh$. As the ball slides down, the potential energy gets converted to kinetic energy. This is because planet Earth does work on the ball by applying a force $F$. The work done by the planet results in a change in the kinetic energy of the system (the system being the ball).
Now, consider a block on a smooth, frictionless table. The block is static so it has no energy. Now, I push the block with a constant force using my hands. The change in the system's (the system being the block) energy must be zero, as was the case for the ball on the mountain. This is because there is practically no difference between the two setups. Both involve a constant force. Both involve two particles (Earth and ball, Hand and ball). So, the increase in kinetic energy of the ball must be matched with a decrease in potential energy. As the ball rolled down the mountain, the increase in its kinetic energy due to the gravitational force was equaled by a decrease in its potential energy (i.e. a decrease in its height). But, for the block placed on a table, what even is the potential energy?
For the ball, the potential energy was $-F_{gravity}\Delta s = -F_{gravity}h$ since the force was constant. What about the block? Would it be $-F_{push}\Delta s$ where $F_{push}$ is the force with which I push the block? What does $\Delta s$ represent in this scenario?

"So, the increase in kinetic energy of the ball must be matched with a decrease in potential energy." Wrong. The whole premise of your post is wrong. An increase in kinetic energy does not have to be matched by  a decrease in potential energy.

If you push on the block you are doing work so you put energy into the system. Where does the energy come from? Your food provides chemical energy which your muscles change into mechanical energy. If you want to think of the energy available in food as a type of potential energy you can, but that is not how potential energy is usually understood

Can you clarify why "...change in the system's (the system being the block) energy must be zero..."? The block clearly gains kinetic energy as you're doing work on it.

I think at least part of OP's error is in assuming that every force can be represented as the negative gradient of a potential energy. Only conservative forces can be represented in such a way. OP maybe is also forgetting that the net work changes the kinetic  energy and that the net force does not have to be made up of all conservative forces.

It's not correct that the block in the table will have no change in energy. That's false. For a purely mechanical system, like the two you outlined, the total energy is just the mechanical energy, the potential + kinetic energy terms. Now, the change in kinetic energy of a system equals the total work applied on the system. Meanwhile, the change in potential energy is opposite to the work applied by conservative forces (those that have a potential energy defined for them). So
$$\Delta K = W_T \ \mathrm{and} \ \ \Delta U =-W_{C}.$$
Then, the change in mechanical energy is
$$\Delta E = \Delta K + \Delta U = W_T - W_C = W_{\mathrm{ext}}+W_{NC} \ \ \mathrm{since} \ \ W_T = W_{\mathrm{ext}} + W_C + W_{NC}. $$
It's a combination of the work done by external and non conservative forces. External forces involve forces that are not originated by the parts of the system. In the case of the block, that would be whatever push you're giving it. Alternatively, you could consider yourself as part of the system, in which case the force is internal but it's also not conservative. The result is, however you slice it, there's a work applied on the block and therefore there is a change in its mechanical energy.
In the case of the ball and Earth, there are no external forces and the only force applied is conservative, so the mechanical energy of the ball is constant.
EDIT: Also, you have to take into account that, while the total energy of an entire system may remain constant, that does not mean that the individual energies do not change precisely because, for any individual part, all interactions are external, they appear as $W_\mathrm{ext}$.

"In the case of the ball and Earth, there are no external forces". If you constraint the system to be just the ball, wouldn't the force of gravity be an external force?

Also, with the block, $W_T = W_C$ since the force imparted by my hand is conservative (because it's just a constant force). So, wouldn't $\Delta E = 0$?

Contact forces don't have potential energies defined for and therefore are not conservative. This is not the same as being under a constant electric field, there is no "field" for a contact force. Basically, there is no change in the mechanical energy of you when you push, but there is a change in the mechanical energy of the block, resulting in a net change in the mechanical energy of the system. If you take into account more forms of energy (mainly, internal energy, the energy in your metabolism), it all balances out.

When considering the ball on the mountain, you can either
(a) think of the ball on its own as a system, in which case gravity - which is an external force - does work on the ball as it rolls down the mountain, increasing the kinetic energy of the ball
or
(b) think of the ball and the Earth as being a system, in which case gravity is an internal force; the energy stored in the gravitational field is potential energy and as the ball rolls down the mountain it exchanges potential energy for kinetic energy.
When you write

As the ball slides down, the potential energy gets converted to kinetic energy. This is because planet Earth does work on the ball ...

you are confusing yourself by conflating (a) and (b). You can have either potential energy or work done by gravity - not both.
In the second scenario - hand pushing ball - the simplest approach is to consider the ball on its own as a system. The force exerted on the ball by the hand is now an external force which does work on the ball and increases its kinetic energy.

I'm confused. Why can't you think of the ball's potential energy when the system is the ball? Isn't it true that the total energy of such a system is conserved?

No. If the ball on its own is a system then its energy is not constant because gravity (an external force) is doing work on it - there is no potential energy in this system. If you want to find a system whose energy is constant then you have to make gravity an internal force, so the system is now Earth + ball, and then you can say that the PE + KE of the Earth + ball system is constant.

As soon as you state, the system being the block, ie a system consisting of one mass, there can be no mention of gravitational potential energy as to define gravitaional potential energy the system must consist of at least two masses.
For such a system, if the only external force is a hand pushing, there will be a change in the kinetic energy of the system.

Consider a ball falling. As it falls, its kinetic energy increases while its potential energy decreases right? Now, consider the exact same scenario but with my hand pushing a block on a horizontal, frictionless surface instead of gravity pulling on the ball. In both cases the force is constant. But, the potential energy of the ball is defined yet that of the block is not. Why?

The equivalent statement for the first scenario is to only the block the system, then the external force is the gravitational attraction on the block due to the Earth, and that external force changes the kinetic energy of the block.
